# How to group by timestamp in UTC by day in R

Tags: r, dplyr, utc

So I have this sample of UTC timestamps and a bunch of other data. I would like to group my data by date. This means I do not need hours/mins/secs and would like to have a new df which shows the number of actions grouped together.

I tried using lubridate to pull out the date but I cant get the origin right.

DATA

```
hw0 <- read.table(text = 
'ID   timestamp        action
4f.. 20160305195246   visitPage
75.. 20160305195302   visitPage
77.. 20160305195312   checkin
42.. 20160305195322   checkin
8f.. 20160305195332   searchResultPage
29.. 20160305195342   checkin', header = T)
```

Here's what I tried

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate) #this will allow us to extract the date
daily <- hw0 %>%
mutate(date=date(as.POSIXct(timestamp),origin='1970-01-01'))

daily <- daily %>%
group_by(date)
```

I am unsure what to use as an origin and my error says this value is incorrect.  Ultimately, I expect the code to return a new df which features a variable (date) with a list of unique dates as well as how many of the different actions there are in each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the numbers at the end are 24 hour time based, you can use:

```
daily = hw0 %>% 
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(as.character(timestamp), format = '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
```

You can use `as.Date` instead if you want to get rid of the hour times. You need to supply the origin when you give a numeric argument, which is interpreted as the number of days since the origin. In your case you should just give it a character vector and supply the date format.

Answer (score 1):

Lubridate also has the `ymd_hms()` function that can extract the date, and the `floor_date()` function that would help.

```
library(tidyverse)
daily <- hw0 %>%
  mutate(time = ymd_hms(timestamp, tz = 'UTC'),
         date = floor_date(time, unit = 'day'))
```

Answer (score 1):

lubridate also has `parse_date_time` which seems to be a nice mix of the above two solutions.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

hw0 %>% 
  mutate(timestamp = parse_date_time(timestamp, order = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))


    ID           timestamp           action
1 4f.. 2016-03-05 19:52:46        visitPage
2 75.. 2016-03-05 19:53:02        visitPage
3 77.. 2016-03-05 19:53:12          checkin
4 42.. 2016-03-05 19:53:22          checkin
5 8f.. 2016-03-05 19:53:32 searchResultPage
6 29.. 2016-03-05 19:53:42          checkin
```